# Only one device can connect to accesspoint created with wifi-ap

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, wireless-access-point

I'm using a Dell Edge Gateway 3001 running Ubuntu Server 18.04 to connect IoT Devices sharing the Ethernet (and GSM later on) connection. I've used the [wifi-ap snap](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/reference/configuration#wifinetmask) to configure the AP and it seem to work. Unfortuantely only one device can connect at a time. I'm trying with a Windows notebook & my IoT device (ESP32), and both can connect, but only if there's no other device connected at that time.

Here's my wifi-ap config

```
debug: true
dhcp.lease-time: 12h
dhcp.range-start: 192.168.7.2
dhcp.range-stop: 192.168.7.101
disabled: false
share.disabled: false
share.network-interface: eth0
wifi.address: 192.168.7.1
wifi.channel: 3
wifi.country-code: DE
wifi.hostapd-driver: nl80211
wifi.interface: wlan0
wifi.interface-mode: direct
wifi.netmask: 255.255.255.0
wifi.operation-mode: g
wifi.security: wpa2
wifi.security-passphrase: MyPassPhrase
wifi.ssid: DellGateway
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to change the operation mode (in my case from 13 to 14) so you can use Bluetooth & Wifi-Access-Point (up to 4 clients) at the same time. This is the Wifi AP Setup code were currently using to configure it properly:

```
sudo apt -y install haveged
sudo modprobe -r rsi_sdio
sudo chmod 777 /etc/modprobe.d/rs9113.conf
sudo echo "options rsi_sdio dev_oper_mode=14" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rs9113.conf
sudo modprobe rsi_sdio
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
sudo nmcli d set wlan0 managed no
snap install wifi-ap
```